# How many ways to build a hamburger?

Tags: permutations

Friendly's recent advertising campaign claims there are over 10 trillion combinations of hamburgers.  Their options are:
Protein (4)
Bread (5)
Cheese (7)
Premium topping (3)
Hot toppings (10)
Cold toppings (8)
Sauces (11)

Their calculation is (4)x(5)x(2^7)x(2^3)x(2^10)x(2^8)x(2^11)=10,995,116,277,760

I think it should be 4x5x7x3x10x8x11=369,600

Thoughts?

Comment: No. There's just one way. If you do it wrong, the hamburger is ruined...

Comment: Their definition of a hamburger is that it must have exactly one protein and exactly one bread, but any number of the other options.

Comment: @Dan: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format questions using Mathjax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their calculation is assuming you can put any number of cheeses/toppings/sauces on your burger, not just one of each.

To elaborate, think about this in binary. If you have $7$ possible cheeses, this corresponds to a bit-string of length $7$. For example, not having any cheese can be written as:

$$0000000$$

while having the first and third types of cheese can be written as

$$1010000.$$

There are $2^7$ possible cheese strings.

In general, when there are $n$ choices, there are $2^n$ possible combinations.

Comment: That makes sense.  It has been a long time since Stats class in college, so it's a little rusty...ok, a lot rusty!  Thanks.

Comment: @Dan This is combinatorics, not statistics!